# Utilize CommandLineJobRunner parameters in job XML

Tags: java, spring-batch

I believe I'm missing something very basic here. I've got a spring-batch batch job I'm modifying to take in a parameter on job run to allow for temp files to be stored in timestamped per job run temp folders. Currently all temp files sit in the same folder and if jobs run non-sequentially the temp files crash into each other.

I have a job runner bat file that I use to actually start the job, and it's creating a timestamp and appending it to the arguments passed to CommandLineJobRunner. So it runs CommandLineJobRunner.main(args) with 3 arguments:

```
String[] args = new String[]{[File.XML], [JobName], build.timestamp=[timestamp]}
CommandLineJobRunner.main(args)
```

In my XML I have the following

```
<bean id="tempfiledir" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
    <constructor-arg value="${batch.file.drive}:/${batch.file.writer.input.root.directory}/${batch.input_file}/${build.timestamp}" />
</bean>
```

The other variables there are set in my batch.properties file. They're obviously static.

From there, I pass the resource into the bean like so:

```
<bean id="[beanTaskletID]" class="[taskletDir]">
    <property name="temporaryFilesDir" ref="tempfiledir"/>
</bean>
```

And then in the actual step I have:

```
<step id="[stepID]">
        <tasklet ref="[beanTaskletID]"/>
        <next on="FAILED" to="[failStepID]"/>
        <next on="COMPLETED" to="[completeStepID]"/>
    </step>
```

Inside my tasklet I'm getting the passed parameter like so:

```
Resource tempDirectory;
public void setTemporaryFilesDir(Resource temporaryFilesDir) {
    this.tempDirectory = temporaryFilesDir;
}
```

When I attempt to run this, I get the following error:

```
lassPathXmlApplicationContext [WARN] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'tempfiledir' defined in class path resource [XML FILE]: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.timestamp' in string value "${batch.file.drive}:/${batch.file.writer.input.root.directory}${batch.input_file}/${build.timestamp}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.timestamp' in string value "${batch.file.drive}:/${batch.file.writer.input.root.directory}${batch.input_file}/${build.timestamp}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:590)
    at com.batch.myJobRunner.main(myJobRunner.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.timestamp' in string value "${batch.file.drive}:/${batch.file.writer.input.root.directory}${batch.input_file}/${build.timestamp}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitGenericArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208)
    ... 11 more
2020-02-14 15:49:36 CommandLineJobRunner [ERROR] Job Terminated in error: Invalid bean definition with name 'tempfiledir' defined in class path resource [XML FILE]: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.timestamp' in string value "${batch.file.drive}:/${batch.file.writer.input.root.directory}${batch.nput_file}/${build.timestamp}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.timestamp' in string value "${batch.file.drive}:/${batch.file.writer.input.root.directory}${batch.input_file}/${build.timestamp}"
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'tempfiledir' defined in class path resource [XML FILE]: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.timestamp' in string value "${batch.file.drive}:/${batch.file.writer.input.root.directory}${batch.input_file}/${build.timestamp}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.timestamp' in string value "${batch.file.drive}:/${batch.file.writer.input.root.directory}${batch.input_file}/${build.timestamp}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:590)
    at com.batch.myJobRunner.main(myJobRunner.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'build.timestamp' in string value "${batch.file.drive}:/${batch.file.writer.input.root.directory}${batch.input_file}/${build.timestamp}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitGenericArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208)
    ... 11 more
```

I thought maybe I needed a declared placeholder for the param being set, so I added the following to batch.properties:

```
build.timestamp=
```

I had read that job params passed in on run will override any properties file setting of the same param. But when I run the job like this, build.timestamp is always just an empty string. So either that isn't the case, or the passed in param on job run isn't actually getting set anywhere.

Either that, or I just very clearly have no idea how to access a passed in parameter from a job run in the XML file. Any help for how to do this would be much appreciated. I've spent hours digging through spring-batch documentation, and nothing has indicated clearly how to access the parameter in the XML file, all it's done is noted you *can* do it. All the documentation I've found for accessing parameters like this successfully work by creating the job in java, rather than having it housed in XML. And clearly that's not my approach to this batch job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access job parameters using Spring Expression Language.

```
#{jobParameters['build.timestamp']}
```

so bean definition will be like this. Since you are using file system resource you can directly inject file to `beanTaskletID`. So no need to define `tempfiledir` bean separately. Don't forget to add scope step.

```
 <bean id="[beanTaskletID]" class="[taskletDir]" scope="step">
        <property name="temporaryFilesDir" value="file:${batch.file.drive}:/${batch.file.writer.input.root.directory}/${batch.input_file}/#{jobParameters['build.timestamp']}"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I knew it had to be something simple. And I want to re-emphasize the importance of adding scope="step", as job parameters aren't actually instantiated until the step starts, so you need to have the bean binding at scope as well, otherwise you'll throw an error at runtime due to job parameters not being found.